# Sum of Zeta function with alternating signs

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am new to Zeta functions.
Looking for some tips to know if the below series is solvable:

$$\mathbb \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\zeta(2k+1)}{2k+1}  $$

Comment: Have you tried writing $\zeta(2k+1)$ as a sum and then reversing the order of summation?

Comment: It is related with $\text{Im}\log\Gamma$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346841/integrate-int-frac-pi2-0-cot-x-dx

Comment: In fact we have $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^k \zeta (2 k+1)}{2 k+1} = \frac{-2 \gamma  \sqrt{x}+\log \left(\Gamma \left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)\right)-\log \left(\Gamma \left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{x}}$$