# Infinite ATAN Sum Expressions - Analytic Solutions?

Tags: sequences-and-series

These infinite sum expressions involving atan appeared recently in an online math puzzle forum:

$S_1 = \tan( \arctan(1) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\arctan(1/2) + \frac{1}{3}\cdot\arctan(1/3) + \frac{1}{4}\cdot\arctan(1/4) + \cdots)$

$S_2 = \tan( \arctan(1) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\arctan(1/2) + \frac{1}{4}\cdot\arctan(1/4) + \frac{1}{8}\cdot\arctan(1/8) + \cdots)$

Am interested to know do these have analytic solutions?

I have found decent ways of approximating them numerically already. But techniques like telescoping sums, power series, recursion don't seem productive for analytic solutions.  $S_1$ appears to have an integral form with a solution that involves the Catalan number $K$, but that's not the same problem, The sums have a good upper bound approximation as the terms become like $\frac{1}{n^2}$ as they get smaller....

Numerical values:

$S_1\approx 6.008$;
$S_2\approx 1.974$

Any help or thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Please add the numerical values.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts in future.

Comment: What is the Catalan number $K$?  I can't find anything on it by Googling.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html

Comment: In the expression for $S_1$, if I substitute the Taylor series for $\arctan$ and reverse the order of summation, I get $\tan\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\zeta(2k+2)$.  [Sums somewhat like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344924/sum-of-zeta-function-with-alternating-signs) have appeared on MSE, but I can't find this one.